# Angular 2: redirect single route to multiple components (4)

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I have a dashboard page with a list of entities in a table. On clicking a entity i navigate to the entity's details page/view using routerLink directive. On that page he can add new records and also view existing records.

The shape of these entities/objects are different so the entity "detail" page would require different logic for forms and displaying records etc for the entities. However these fall into roughly 4 categories, so i have 4 different components to handle 4 different "shapes".

Now i am looking for a clean, generic way to intercept and divert a single route definition to these 4 components, i cannot hardcode it in the dashboard entity list table because it will be loaded on the fly:

Possible directions (from my understanding)

- Maybe build a shell component, subscribe to route params and then maintain a mapping of which entity should be directed at which of the 4 components. i.e entity 4,6,7 goto entity.detail.componentA. Then, call router.navigate to the required component.
- use a single component and fetch the entity records, check shape and display accordingly. This will make a bulky component with lots of ng-if in template for showing the correct view.

-use a single shell component and include the 4 component selector in the shell template i.e.Disable/enable components based on view using ng-if's and flags.

If somebody has gone through a similar problem, please share your views.

Current route looks like this:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'entity-details/:id', component: EntityDetailsComponent }
];
```

Comment: I would suggest using a wrapper component, that contains your 4 entity-detail-components and displays one of them depending on your entity.

Comment: So you are suggesting to make a single bulky component and use ngif to enable/disable appropriate views. So why should I not create 4 different components and route to them accordingly ?.

Comment: No, I meant you have your 4 detail-components, e.g. Entity1-Detail through Entity4-Detail. And you have your Entity-Wrapper-Component with a template that looks like `<entity-1 *ngIf="showEntity1"></entity-1> <entity-2 *ngIf="...">...`. This way you add just a very small layer above your detail component where you can handle the decision which entity should be displayed.